# substring index as new data.table column

Tags: r, data.table

I want to record the location of the first match of a pattern (XXX) against a string column (col1) into a separate column, using `data.table`. The following attempt has two problems, (i) it fails when there's no match (`character(0)`) and (ii) does not seem to return a vector in the way `data.table` expects:

```
data[,XXX.pos:=grep('XXX',col1,fixed=TRUE)]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share a few rows of sample data that illustrate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` doesn't record where in a string a pattern occurs. You can use `stringr::str_locate` for that:

```r
library(data.table)
quux <- data.table(txt = c("quux", "over here", "under there"))
quux[, pos := stringr::str_locate(txt, "u")[,"start"]]
quux
#            txt   pos
#         <char> <int>
# 1:        quux     2
# 2:   over here    NA
# 3: under there     1
```